# react-loadable babel-plugin-import-inspector is not working

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-loadable

Issue:

when i try to launch node server console screams:

```
/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:173
throw new Error("This API has been removed. If you're looking for this " + "functionality in Babel 7, you should import the " + "'@babel/helper-module-imports' module and use the functions exposed " + " from that module, such as 'addNamed' or 'addDefault'.");
```

I found out that it's babel-plugin-import-inspector that uses function addImport() which in turns is deprecated and throws an error.

I cannot stop using this plugin as it's highly connected with react-loadable ;(

What should I do in such a situtation? My babel version is 7, may be I should downgrade?

By the way, babel offers me to use @babel/helper-module-imports and use functions exposed from that module, but I don't understand how to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded and it looks like everything is working now.